# Putting JSON contents in HTML table, only index working

Tags: javascript, html, json

For an HTML site, I use a JSON file from a website to fill a table.

My script looks like this:

```
    <script>
      fetch ("[LINK]")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
          addData(data);
        })
      function addData(data){
       var table = document.getElementById("apiinventory");


       let text = "";
       for (x in data) {
       var row = table.insertRow(0);
       var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
       var cellPrice = row.insertCell(1);
       var cellAmount = row.insertCell(2);
       cellName.innerHTML = x;
       text += x;
       }
      }
    </script>
```

And my JSON file looks like this: (only a snippet of two of the objects inside it)

```
{"CS20": "{"0":{"date":"Oct 18 2019 01: +0","price":5.467,"casesLeft":"55948"},"1":{"date":"Oct 19 2019 01: +0","price":2.992,"casesLeft":"267246"}}, "Operation Phoenix Weapon Case": "{\"0\":{\"date\":\"Feb 21 2014 01: +0\",\"price\":5.714,\"casesLeft\":\"24633\"},\"1\":{\"date\":\"Feb 22 2014 01: +0\",\"price\":3.814,\"casesLeft\":\"23002\"}
```

I managed to display the names of the objects (CS20, Operation Phoenix Weapon Case) in my first cell, but I don't manage to get the values of date, price and casesLeft into the other cells.

I.e. this:

```
cellPrice.innerText = data[x].price
```

does not work for me, it only prints "undefined" in that given cell.

Is there any other way for me getting these values into the table or am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @spectric can you elaborate? I am not that educated in it, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried parsing it? It's invalid.

Comment: @spectric yes, but i read different things and i was honestly confused, but I didn't know where the mistake was. can you elaborate what the problem in the JSON is? It's made by me / my team, we can fix it if we know what the problem is.

Comment: The JSON is indeed invalid, I presume `"CS20": "{"` you need to remove the `"` before the `{` here.

After that, please fix the value of the `"Operation Phoenix Weapon Case"` property. Either make it a proper JSON or a properly escaped string.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov Alright, thank you! You really saved our group project i think, we would have never spotted this. Have a good day!

Comment: @DmitriyPopov Hey, maybe you could help with the problem we ran into with fixing the JSON. We are converting a dataframe in python with `pricesDf.to_json(orient="index")`, it adds that `"` automatically when converting. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @MerX Please start a new question.